# How do I write a wrapper powershell command that forwards all arguments to a delegate command?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

**wrapper** is supposed to just call **delegate**, forwarding the arguments that were passed to wrapper.

**Given**

```
.\wrapper.ps1 1 2
```

**When** delegate.ps1 contents:

```
param($one, $two)
write-host "one=$one and two=$two"
```

**Then** expect output to be:

```
one=1 and two=2
```

**wrapper.ps1 contents:**

```
.\delegate # How do I forward all args passed to this wrapper script to the delegate script?
```

If I try the following implementation of wrapper.ps1:

```
.\delegate $args
```

The output is incorrectly:

```
one=1 2 and two=
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6)

Use the @ symbol

```
.\delegate @args
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6#using-splatting-to-represent-command-parameters

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell provides a `ProxyCommand` class designed to make this easy. To generate the text of a wrapper function for a command, say `MyCommand`, you would do

```
$wrapper = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((get-command MyCommand))
```

Comment: I'll have to look into this. Thanks!

Comment: This is the better answer. `$wrapper` then contains a very comprehensive wrapper for the target command which you can then modify to suit.

Comment: Hey, BruceP.  Shouldn't that line you posted be this way? …  $MyCommand = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command Get-Service);($wrapper = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MyCommand))   … Otherwise that line by itself will fail  with 'get-command : The term 'MyCommand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,'

Comment: In my example I'm using "MyCommand" as a placeholder for the actual command that the user wants to wrap. So, for example, if that command is `Get-Service` then it would be `$wrapper = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Command Get-Service)) `

Comment: It's also worth noting, that [`System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) has a few other methods, which return the individual blocks of the wrapper function text (`cmdletbinding`, `param`, `begin`, `process`, `end` etc.). This comes in handy when auto-generating a large number of wrapper function, as one can easily surround these blocks with custom code (or do some search/replace), before concating them to the full function text.

Comment: For details on using the `ProxyCommand`, see: [How to wrap a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77635452/1701026)