# PowerShell middleware to wrap powershell module commands

Tags: powershell, module, middleware

I am looking for a middleware pipeline option for PowerShell. That means I want to provide each function with pre and post statements for a module that is not a C# cmlet.

Is there already something in this direction?

The background is that I don't want to store debug functions at every command but want to measure all my functions at a central place.

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe [ProxyCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50846498/503046) would help?

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to put code in front of a call to a cmdlet, or after like you can when writing your own functions or using something like try\catch\finally. You cant really emulate that type of a work flow with cmdlet calls that I have found.

Comment: I disagree, while you can't modify how PowerShell invokes cmdlets and functions, you can write your own wrapper functions.