# Is there any way I can use rm -rf in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, rm

I know that I can use `rm -r -fo` to remove a folder and all its content in PowerShell. But is there any way I can use `rm -rf` in PowerShell?

I tried to add the below scripts into my `$Profile`, but both did not work.

1. First try:

   ```
   function rm -rf() {
       rm -r -fo
   }
   ```
2. Second try:

   ```
   Set-Alias rm -rf "rm -r -fo"
   ```

Comment: For those of us not knowing `rm` and the option `-rf` you may explain what it does. I'm pretty usre there is a way to replicate that in PowerShell. ‍♂️ Or are you referring to the alias for `Remove-Item`?

Comment: @Olaf `rm` is a command in Unix OS which can remove file or folder, meanwhile it's the alias of `Remove-Item` in PowerShell. For `-rf`,  in Unix it means a bundle argument of `-r`: recursive remove all contents in folder, and `-f`: force remove items without human confirm.

Comment: Since you can set an alias in PowerShell and you could set the default parameters for a cmdlet it would be a combination of these two steps you need.  You seem to know already `Set-Alias` so you just need to read up about [about_Parameters_Default_Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.4) 

Comment: If that's not what you meant you still could write a function doing exactly what you want.

Comment: As Olaf suggests, you might [write a proxy-command (wrapper)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77635453/1701026)

Comment: @Olaf Dude I think I got your point. You mean I can set `-r -fo` as default params of `rm`, and storage it into my `$Profile`, right? It's a good suggestion, but a kind of different with what I really want. If I do this, my `rm` command will be executed with `-r -fo` args forever, whereas sometimes I just don't want these two args. 

For your second suggestion, I've tried, but since there's a space between `rm` and `-rf`, PowerShell prompts me it's an illegal syntax.

Comment: @Iron after a quick view of your post, I guess it's a customer for PowerShell which I can add a pipe and my customized function name after my command? It may also not what I want, I just wanna execute `rm -rf` **without** any extra characters, just like what I did in Unix.

Comment: Since you would need to type 6 characters anyway with your approach why not creating a function with the name of `rm-rf`? There you can add whatever you want and it shouldn't interfere with any existing alias or cmdlet. 

Comment: And just out of curiousity - how often do you have to type this command to feel the urge to spend some effort to replicate it in PowerShell? I'd expect you wouldn't waste that much time typing 3 characters more in PowerShell to actually make the difference count.  ‍♂️

Comment: @Olaf Due to work reasons, I use windows and Unix every day, what I want is to use same commends for the same purpose in two different OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can write a proxy function, that adds the `-rf` parameter to `Remove-Item`. If you then set the alias `rm` to point to your proxy function instead of `Remove-Item`, you will be able to use `rm -rf` like in Unix, while still having the opportunity to use all other parameters of `Remove-Item`. You will basically have `Remove-Item` with the *additional* parameter `-rf`.

As documented in [iRon's excellent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77635453/11942268), you can generate the proxy function body with the following commands:

```
$MetaData = [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData](Get-Command Remove-Item)
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData)
```

Which will give you:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Path', SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium', SupportsTransactions=$true, HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373')]
param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]
    ${Path},

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralPath', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [string[]]
    ${LiteralPath},

    [string]
    ${Filter},

    [string[]]
    ${Include},

    [string[]]
    ${Exclude},

    [switch]
    ${Recurse},

    [switch]
    ${Force},

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [pscredential]
    [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
    ${Credential})


dynamicparam
{
    try {
        $targetCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Remove-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet, $PSBoundParameters)
        $dynamicParams = @($targetCmd.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Where-Object { $_.Value.IsDynamic })
        if ($dynamicParams.Length -gt 0)
        {
            $paramDictionary = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
            foreach ($param in $dynamicParams)
            {
                $param = $param.Value

                if(-not $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.ContainsKey($param.Name))
                {
                    $dynParam = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new($param.Name, $param.ParameterType, $param.Attributes)
                    $paramDictionary.Add($param.Name, $dynParam)
                }
            }
            return $paramDictionary
        }
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

begin
{
    try {
        $outBuffer = $null
        if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
        {
            $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
        }
        $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Remove-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
        $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
        $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

process
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

end
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}
<#

.ForwardHelpTargetName Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Remove-Item
.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

#>
```

You can paste this – as is – directly into your own function definition and you will already have a function that does the same as `Remove-Item`.

To add the parameter `-rf`, add the the following parameter definition:

```
[Alias('RF')]
[switch]
$RecurseForce
```

To not pass it to `Remove-Item` directly, add the following line to the `dynamicparam` block:

```
$PSBoundParameters.Remove('RecurseForce') | Out-Null
```

Then you just need to handle the call of `Remove-Item`, when the `-rf` parameter is provided. To do so, change the line `$scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }` to:

```
if ($RecurseForce) {
    $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters -Recurse -Force }
} else {
    $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
}
```

Furthermore, it is [recommended](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10863#issuecomment-545621624) to remove the `OutBuffer`-related code and to replace all `throw` statements by `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)`.

In the following full example, I named the proxy function `Remove-ItemProxy` and made all the changes I already described. In the end I call `Set-Alias` to make it available through `rm`. No worries, `Set-Alias` will only affect your current session and won't alter your system permanently. You can copy and paste the following block into your [PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles) and whenever you open a PowerShell session, you will be able to use `rm -rf`:

```
function Remove-ItemProxy {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Path', SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium', SupportsTransactions=$true, HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        ${Path},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralPath', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]]
        ${LiteralPath},

        [string]
        ${Filter},

        [string[]]
        ${Include},

        [string[]]
        ${Exclude},

        [switch]
        ${Recurse},

        [switch]
        ${Force},

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [pscredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
        ${Credential},
        
        [Alias('RF')]
        [switch]
        $RecurseForce)


    dynamicparam
    {
        try {
            $PSBoundParameters.Remove('RecurseForce') | Out-Null
            $targetCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Remove-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet, $PSBoundParameters)
            $dynamicParams = @($targetCmd.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Where-Object { $_.Value.IsDynamic })
            if ($dynamicParams.Length -gt 0)
            {
                $paramDictionary = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
                foreach ($param in $dynamicParams)
                {
                    $param = $param.Value

                    if(-not $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.ContainsKey($param.Name))
                    {
                        $dynParam = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new($param.Name, $param.ParameterType, $param.Attributes)
                        $paramDictionary.Add($param.Name, $dynParam)
                    }
                }
                return $paramDictionary
            }
        } catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }

    begin
    {
        try {
            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Remove-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            if ($RecurseForce) {
                $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters -Recurse -Force }
            } else {
                $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
            }
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        } catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }

    process
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
        } catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }

    end
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }
    <#

    .ForwardHelpTargetName Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Remove-Item
    .ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

    #>
}

Set-Alias -Name rm -Value Remove-ItemProxy -Option AllScope
```

Comment: You might  consider to use `RF` as an alias: `[Alias('RF')][switch]${RecurseForce}`. To @AaronHao, best PowerShell practice: [Always use the full name for cmdlets and parameters. Avoid using aliases unless you're specifically demonstrating the alias.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/community/contributing/powershell-style-guide#formatting-command-syntax-elements). Also note that there is a [known issue with `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/1701026) which you might want work around if you create a proxy command for your customer anyways.

Comment: Related: [`#21349` Proxy command fails when additional parameter is used](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21349)

Answer (score 2):

**[stackprotector's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171751/45375) is definitely the best solution**: it wraps `Remove-Item` in *all* aspects, including tab-completion, streaming pipeline-input support, and integration with [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help):

To offer a **simpler - but limited - alternative**, which is **easier to author**, however:

```
Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore Alias:rm # remove the built-in `rm` alias

# Simple (non-advanced) wrapper function
function rm {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
  Wrapper for Remove-Item with support for -rf to mean -Recurse -Force
#>
  param([switch] $rf)  # Custom -rf switch
  # If -rf was specified, translate it into the -Recurse -Force switches
  # via a hashtable to be used for splatting.
  $extraArgs = if ($rf) { @{ Recurse=$true; Force=$true } } else { @{} }
  # Invoke Remove-Item with any extra arguments and all pass-through arguments.
  if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {  # pipeline input present
    $input | Remove-Item @args @extraArgs
  } else { 
    Remove-Item @args @extraArgs 
  }
}
```

Limitations:

- No tab-completion support for `Remove-Item`'s parameters (you do get it for `-rf`, and by default the files and directories in the current directory also tab-complete)
- Only simple `Get-Help` / `-?` output, focused on `-rf` only (conversely, however, forwarding the help to `Remove-Item`, as in the proxy-function approach, doesn't describe the custom `-rf` parameter at all).
- While pipeline input is supported, it is collected in full up front, unlike with the proxy-function approach.

Note:

- The solution relies on [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) to pass arguments (passing arguments stored in a hashtable or array variable by prefixing that variable with `@`).

  - In *non*-[advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) functions, such as in this case, the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) contains all arguments that weren't bound to declared parameters, and `@args` passes them through via splatting.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - Splatting an *empty* [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{}`) results in *no* arguments being passed, as desired (ditto for an empty *array*, `@()`).
- `$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` indicates whether pipeline input is present, which can then be enumerated via the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input); as noted, doing so requires collecting all input objects in memory first, given that functions without a `process` block are only executed *after* all pipeline input has been received (i.e., they execute as if their body were in an `end` block).

---

<sup>[1] Note that the automatic `$args` variable contains an *array*, and while splatting with an array - as opposed to with a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) - normally doesn't support passing *named* arguments through (those preceded with their target parameter name, e.g. `-Path *.txt`), `$args` has magic built into it that supports that too. For the details of this magic, see the footnote of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71037345/45375).</sup>